# How do I return my skin model back to Steve?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was just playing minecraft normally with the Kovacics Mod Pack as Steve, i was just placing blocks, checking out the features of the KMP (assassins creed,Smart Moves,Instant Structures, etc)
I then decided to place a modern house structure using the instant structures and then my minecraft crashed.
So I re-opened it and went back onto my world> I then spawned and saw my default skin model has changed from Steve to Alex. How do I change my skin back to default Steve?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening your game? Are you using the latest version of Minecraft and... Have you tried changing your skin on the website?

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy to return from the Alex (3-block-arms-and-leg) model to the Steve (normal) model.

### 1. Log into minecraft.net

This step is simple enough. Go here: http://minecraft.net/login

### 2. [Go to your profile](http://minecraft.net/profile).

[image: Go to the profile tab]

### 3. Modify your settings and save.

[image: Select the Steve model]

Answer (score -4):

In version 1.8 you cannot change skin to Steve because the update doesn't allow you to.Maybe you can download a model of Steve on some site.SO you have to play at least 1.7 because in 1.8 Alex is original model

Comment: It is quite possible. I managed to do it by removing my Alex skin in the jar files and replacing it with an original Steve. And Alex is not the original model, it is random which one you get.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson feel free to add that as an answer

Comment: @Ben I was going to do that. However, I did notice that the question was asking about the skin *model* rather than the actual skin, so I decided not to.

Comment: @KrešoBertić - One grammatical error: versions 1.7 or earlier **not** *or later*. Also, it does allow you to change; go to the website.

Comment: sry Im Croatian